# SOLR indexing arbitrary data

Tags: solr

Let's say you have a simple forms automation application, and you want to index every submitted form in a Solr collection. Let's also say that form content is open-ended so that the user can create custom fields on the form and so forth.

Since users can define custom forms, you can't really predefine fields to Solr, so we've been using Solr's "schema-less" or managed schema mode. It works well, except for one problem.

Let's say a form comes through with a field called "ID" and a value of "9". If this is the first time Solr has seen a field called "ID", it dutifully updates it's schema, and since the value of this field is numeric, Solr assigns it a data type of one of it's numeric data types (we see "plong" a lot).

Now, let's say that the next day, someone submits another instance of this same form, but in the ID field, they type their name instead of entering a number. Solr spits this out and won't index this record because the schema says ID should be numeric, but on this record, it's not.

The way we've been dealing with this so far is to trap the exception we get when a field's data type disagrees with the schema, and then we use the Solr API to alter the schema, making the field in question a text or string instead of a numeric.

Of course, when we do this, we need to reindex the entire collection since the schema changed, and so we need to persist all the original data just in case we need to re-index everything after one of these schema data-type collisions. We're big Solr fans, but at the same time, we wonder whether the benefits of using the search engine outweigh all this extra work that gets triggered if a user simply enters character data in a previously numeric field.

Is there a way to just have Solr always assign something like "text_general" for every field, or is there some other better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you might need to handle the `Id` values at your application end.
It would be good to add a validation for `Id`, that `Id` should be of either `string` or `numberic`.
This would resolve your issue permanently. If this type is decided you don't have to do anything on the `solr` side.

The alternative approach would be have a fixed `schema.xml`.
In this add a field `Id` with a fixed `fieldType`.
I would suggest you to go with `string` as a fieldType for ID if don't want it to tokenize the data and want the exact match in the search.

If you would like to have flexibility in search for the `Id` field then you can add a `text_general` field type for the field.

You can create your own `fieldType` as well with provided `tokenizer` and `filter` according to your requirement for you the field `Id`.

Also don't use the schemaless mode in production. You can also map your field names to a dynamic field definition. Create a dynamic field such as `*_t` for the text fields. All your fields with ending with `_t` will be mapped to this.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to manage the field such that we wouldn't have this same problem. The form displayed to the user has a control declared as a non-numeric string - if the first user to enter data into this field enters a number, Solr interprets it as an numeric field, even though it's not - and then when someone subsequently enters a (totally valid) non-numeric value, Solr isn't going to index that record because of the type mismatch.

Comment: so you define the field in solr called as Id and with type text and you map your incoming data to this field. how are you indexing the data..?Dont run the solr in schemaless mode.....

Comment: 1) Don't use the schemaless mode in production (because of the issue you've encountered) 2) Map your field names to something matching a dynamic field definition, such as `<name>_t` for text fields. There is no need to keep a 1:1 mapping between form field names and the field names in the index.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Apologies - I'm just not as fluent in Solr as I should be, so I'm hoping you can give me a better example. Suppose we have XML like this: <custom_field>some value</custom_field>. Today, once this is indexed in Solr, we can do searches for particular values of "custom_field" by specifying "custom_field=whatever" in the search. Are you suggesting changing this to a constant field name and value predefined as text (say, like  <field_name>custom_field</field_name>)? If we did this, how would the user search for a particular value of "custom_field"?

Comment: Solr's Schema is the definition that Solr uses to determine how to index a field for searchability and how to process the field. If you're not [setting up a schema using `schema.xml` or the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/documents-fields-and-schema-design.html), then the type of the first value indexed for that field type will be used. For the second use case I suggest defining a dynamic field in the schema named `*_t` which means everything ending in `_t` will be processed as text, then sending in `<field name="custom_field_t">some value</field>` (the Solr syntax)